# Elastic search ignore tf in match_phrase query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to solve the following problem. I generate match_phrase queries and I want to ignore Term Frequencies in the score.

I tried with constant queries but:

"[constant_score] query does not support [match_phrase]"

Then I tried to write a custom similarity function but side plugins seam not to be supported anymore.

Any other idea?

Thank you

Comment: You'd better post your query..

Comment: The query is: curl -XPOST localhost:9200/en/_search?pretty -d ' {
    "query": { 
                "match_phrase" : { "lex" : "Hello"}  
    }                                                
}' but I want to have the default similarity except the tf not considered. So if there is a document containing "Hello Hello" and one containing only "Hello" the first is down-ranked with respect to the second since it is longer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow. `match_phrase` in `constant_score` should work:

```
GET /<index>/_search
{
    "query": {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "match_phrase" : { "<field>" : "<phrase>"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this works, but it removes every other similarity metric, especially the length of the document is not considered. And I need that. I want to privilege short documents.